# Passing data from Fragment to Activity null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I know this is a very asked question but i have done my research on it and still didn't manage to come up with a valid solution.

Problem is i try to send data from fragment like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),EditReceiptActivity.class);
                System.out.println("RECEIPT IN SETTINGS: "+ receipt);
                intent.putExtra("receipt_to_be_edited", receipt);
                startActivity(intent);
```

this is done in a fragment context.

and then when i try to retrive this data in an activity context:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Receipt value = (Receipt) extras.getSerializable("receipt_to_be_edited");
            System.out.println("RECEIPT ON RESUME: "+ value);
            FolderDataSource f = new FolderDataSource(getApplicationContext());
            f.open();
            String name = f.getFolderName(value.getId());
            f.close();
            folder_title.setText(name);
            details_txt.setText(value.getDetails());
            value_txt.setText(value.getValue());
            category_picked_txt.setText(value.getCategory());
            folder_picked_txt.setText(name);
            currency_picked_txt.setText(value.getCurrency());
            location_picked_txt.setText(value.getLocation());
            setImageView();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
```

I get a null pointer exception... even though the prints are there... the null pointer exception is on the line:

```
            String name = f.getFolderName(value.getId());
```

**EDIT**

The problem was my method getFolderName(), that was returning null, so there is nothing wrong with my passing information code!

So this could turn out to be yet another example of how to pass information from fragment to activity via Intent!

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. check the topic communicating with activity.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, my code works fine now:)